# How i can Delete image from users table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have multiple fields in my users table in laravel but i want to delete only image from users table, Please let me know the process.
Here are my usercontroller.php file..

```
public function userprofile(Request $request)
{

    $user = DB::table('users')->where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    //dd($user);
    $userWish = DB::table('package_wishlist')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('is_active',1)->count();

    $userComp = DB::table('package_comparison')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('is_active',1)->count();

    $bookings = DB::table('agent_bookings')
                ->where('cust_email',Auth::user()->email)->get();
     return view('user/profile',['bookings'=>$bookings,'user'=>$user[0],'userWish'=>$userWish,'userComp'=>$userComp]);

}

public function imagedestroy($id)
{
    $image = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $file= $image->user_image;
    $filename = public_path().'/uploads/user_uploads/'.$image;
    File::delete($filename);
}
```

And here is my profile.blade.php file..

```
@foreach($user as $delimage)
 <a onclick="event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('delete-image-form').submit();" 
 class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block">Delete</a>
 <form id="delete-image-form" method="POST" action="{{ 
 route('delimage.imagedestroy', $delimage->id) }}"  
 style="display: none;">
  @method('DELETE')
  @csrf
</form>
@endforeach
```

And my web.php file is this...

```
Route::get('/userprofile', 'CustomHomeController@userprofile')->name('userprofile');
Route::get('/userprofile/{id}', 'CustomHomeController@imagedestroy')->name('imagedestroy');
```

Comment: use method get and check dd and confirm you get the id or not

Comment: and which error you are getting btw??
will you please check and tell what you get when you try `dd($image);`

Comment: I am getting this error `Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: did you try get method in form?

Comment: yes, i try get method but still same error

Comment: tried `dd($image);` ???

Comment: you need not to use get method. Laravel use delete method for deleting an entry. your form is ok. problem is in your controller. check out my answer.

Comment: i tried `dd($image)` but it's giving me same error..

Comment: why you wrote 2 methods use only 1

Comment: Try removing your loop in the frontend as you are returning only 1 user.
Also, any particular reason why you are using `DB` facade instead of the eloquent representations? Your code is misleading, as you are targeting a `profile` but querying `users` and then looping users but you search by `id`. Make use of the `User::find($id)` to return that user and that user only, imho

Answer (score 1):

use first() instead of get(). get() gives you a collection which you need to iterate to get an attribute. so you just can't get image of a user like

```
$image = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
$file= $image->user_image; //this won't work.
```

Try like

```
public function imagedestroy($id)
{
    $image = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $file= $image->user_image;
    $filename = public_path().'/uploads/user_uploads/'.$image;
    File::delete($filename);
}
```

And your userprofile method should be like

```
public function userprofile(Request $request)
{

    $user = DB::table('users')->where('id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    //dd($user);
    $userWish = DB::table('package_wishlist')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('is_active',1)->count();

    $userComp = DB::table('package_comparison')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('is_active',1)->count();

    $bookings = DB::table('agent_bookings')
                ->where('cust_email',Auth::user()->email)->get();
     return view('user/profile',['bookings'=>$bookings,'user'=>$user,'userWish'=>$userWish,'userComp'=>$userComp]);

}
```

So you don't need to iterate in view. just use

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('delete-image-form').submit();" 
 class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block">Delete</a>
<form id="delete-image-form" method="POST" action="{{ 
 route('imagedestroy', $user->id) }}"  
 style="display: none;">
  @method('DELETE')
  @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object ` getting this error on view page...

Comment: I am using these routes for delete and display please check once...
`Route::get('/userprofile', 'CustomHomeController@userprofile')->name('userprofile');`
`Route::get('/userprofile/{id}', 'CustomHomeController@imagedestroy')->name('imagedestroy');`

Comment: well i can see you are using the route name as `imagedestroy` in `web.php` but in view its `delimage.imagedestroy`. Is `delimage` is a prefix? If not just use `imagedestroy` as the route in the view.

Comment: And use Laravel Eloquent instead of DB facade. Its a good practice. :)